# Efficiently insert into table in Postgres

Tags: sql, r, postgresql

In my database, I save a tree-like datastructure as a table `tab` with the columns `id` (primary key), `value`, `from_id` and `depth`, where `depth` (integer) represents the distance from the root of the tree.

Now I would like to add rows to the table `tab` from another table `candidates` (columns `id, value, from_id`), but with two restrictions: 1) only new `id` and 2) only rows where the `depth` is below some given treshold (e.g. 3 or 4).

There may be more than one `from_id` in `tab` that point to a new row in `candidates`.

Being a Postgres beginner, I hope my approach is correct however very inefficient:

```
insert into tab
select distinct c.id, c.value, c.from_id, t.depth+1 as depth
from candidates as c
join tab as t on t.id=c.from_id
where depth<3 and c.id not in
(select id from tab);
```

I am looking for suggestions to speed this up. Together with two other operations in one transaction, this takes several minutes for less than 10k rows.

I am working from `R`, using the `RPostgres` package, however I believe this is more a SQL / database problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try if left joining `tab` and checking for its `id`s to be `NULL` brings you a benefit.

```
INSERT INTO tab
            (id,
             value,
             from_id,
             depth)
SELECT c1.id,
       c1.value,
       c1.from_id,
       t1.depth + 1
       FROM candidates c1
            INNER JOIN tab t1
                       ON t1.id = c1.from_key
            LEFT JOIN tab t2
                      ON t2.id = c1.id
       WHERE t1.depth + 1 < 3
             AND t2.id IS NULL;
```

Along with this try to put indexes on `tab (id, depth)` and `candidates (from_key)`.

Another option is a correlated subquery with `NOT EXISTS`.

```
INSERT INTO tab
            (id,
             value,
             from_id,
             depth)
SELECT c1.id,
       c1.value,
       c1.from_id,
       t1.depth + 1
       FROM candidates c1
            INNER JOIN tab t1
                       ON t1.id = c1.from_key
       WHERE t1.depth + 1 < 3
             AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                    FROM tab t2
                                    WHERE t2.id = c1.id);
```

Either way you likely need to get rid of the `IN` clause if `tab` has a lot of rows to improve performance.

And get accustomed to always explicitly write down the target columns in an `INSERT` statement as the statement may otherwise break if you make changes to the target table, e.g. adding a column.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It helped a lot.